# bi-directional relation loses sorting when child record is saved

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

In my own extension I have a bi-directional mm-relation between categories and items using an mm-table.

mm-table has 4 columns uid_local, uid_foreign, sorting, sorting_foreign.

TCA for both object tables is (only important parts)
categories table:

```
'items' => array(
    'l10n_display' => 'defaultAsReadonly',
    'l10n_mode' => 'exclude',
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'renderType' => 'selectMultipleSideBySide',
        'foreign_table' => 'tx_records_domain_model_item',
        'foreign_table_where' => ' AND tx_records_domain_model_item.sys_language_uid = ###REC_FIELD_sys_language_uid###',
        'MM' => 'tx_records_item_category_mm',
    ),
),
```

and items table

```
'categories' => array(
    'exclude' => 0,
    'l10n_display' => 'defaultAsReadonly',
    'l10n_mode' => 'exclude',
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'renderType' => 'selectMultipleSideBySide',
        'foreign_table' => 'tx_records_domain_model_category',
        'foreign_table_where' => ' AND tx_records_domain_model_category.sys_language_uid = ###REC_FIELD_sys_language_uid###',
        'MM' => 'tx_records_item_category_mm',
        'MM_opposite_field' => 'items',
    ),
),
```

I have 4 languages. Now for my problem.

I have a category with uid 7. The items are added and sorted in my select field. Output in front end is in the given order as set in the backend.

But now – when I update one of the items of the category that item will be placed before all other items in front end while the sorting in the back end is still as it was before the item's update. If i save the category afterwards, the front end will show the desired sorting again.

During my research I found that the mm table shows strange records. When the front end output is correct, I have one record per item in the category, and sorting is from 1 through 13.
After the item's update, I find three new records in the mm table. Three for three additional languages. These three records show my categories local_uid==7, foreign_uids are the uids of the localized item records, sorting_local is equal to 0 for all three records. I suggest this results in the wrong fornt end output although the primary language record still has the old sorting value. That's why it is shown correctly in the backend's category form.

Why do I find those 3 additional records after the item's update. The combination of the primary language's category uid with the localized uids of the items can not be correct.

Any suggestions?

Comment: is it about updating the records in Backend or in Frontend? Is `extbase` involved in the Frontend?

Comment: updates are done only in back end. Front end output is done with extbase/fluid

Answer (score 1):

I could make it work by setting `l10n_mode => ''` in the items table. To be honest, I do not exactly understand what happens there now, but it works.

Hint found on https://forge.typo3.org/issues/57272